# What is this fleshy-stemmed plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant came (seemingly by accident) with another pot plant a few years ago in a plant sale.  Unfortunately, we do not remember what the original plant was that it came with.

- It was initially one of the small 'fleshy stems' you can see in the photos, about 2cm in length.
- If you do not water it, the leaves fall off and leave the fleshy stems
- If it is watered, a new section of stem is grown with leaves.
- Its existing stems do not seem to regrow their leaves if they drop off.
- It was acquired in the South-West of England.
- It does not appear to be affected by the time of year.

Photos (click to enlarge):

[image: Unknown plant - photo 1]
[image: Unknown plant - photo 2]

Comment: Does it ever grow flowers? If so, can you provide pictures or a description of them?

Comment: I've never seen it flower.  Also, whilst I appreciate the "click to enlarge" change to my post, please don't correct the grammar in my post from British English to American English, thanks.  I'm also a little unsure why you removed the disclaimer from the top of the original question.  You describe it as unnecessary in your Edit, but surely it was important to put in case this was the wrong StackExchange site?

Comment: sorry didn't realize some of the phrasing was British! Of course feel free to roll back edits if you don't like them. I removed the disclaimer paragraph to indicate that, yes, this post is ok here and therefore the paragraph was not needed. Thanks for including it initially, but it would only serve as clutter moving forward.

Comment: Also, FYI: gardening.stackExchange also accepts plant ID questions -- it's really up to you where to post, but they are probably a bit more horticulturally inclined. I don't spend much time there, so I can't comment on their accuracy, though :p.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of ***Senecio articulatus*** (Candle Plant; hot dog cactus), a succulent plant in the broad (aka polyphyletic) [*Senecio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senecio) genus ([Asteraceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteraceae)).

[image]

<sup>Source: [U. Wisconsin-Eau Calire](https://greenhouse.apps.uwec.edu/plants/173)</sup>

Based on my limited knowledge of the plant and the variable leaf shape, I am not sure if this is your species or not. However, I'm sure some additional searching using this species as a guide will get you to the correct species/cultivar.

[World of Succulents](https://worldofsucculents.com/senecio-articulatus-candle-plant-hot-dog-cactus/) provides some additional information on *Senecio articulatus*.

You can see a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNHjs8izyUI) of a *Senecio* succulent identified as *S. articulatus* for better comparison to your plant:

[image]

Comment: This does certainly look like it!  The leaves certainly seem similar, and the colour seems right, not to mention fleshy stems!  The picture in the World of Succulents link does look like it has grown very differently though, but I don't know if that would be because the growth has been carefully managed?

Comment: Again, I'm not too knowledgeable on this plant. It's very likely that yours is a different species or cultiva in the genus. I welcome you to dig around a bit yourself and let me know if I can update this answer in any way to make it more accurate/useful.

Comment: It is likely that I'll accept this answer at some point once I'm done digging, and I'll post another comment if I feel that it could be improved with another comment.  Rest assured that I've not forgotten about this answer!

Comment: @Interminable no worries. I encourage you to dig around as I'm not 100% sure this is a correct answer. No rush. Feel free to add/update/comment about anything you find! (or feel free to add your own updated answer if appropriate!)

Comment: @Interminable please feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied and found no further information. Thanks :).